# Embed libclang in an iOS app

Tags: makefile, static-libraries, llvm, clang

I need to use [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org) in an iOS app (for diagnostics and syntax highlighting) but I can't seem to figure out how to build it as is, let alone for iOS. Using CMake I generated an Xcode project for LLVM, but Xcode ran out of memory and disk space for swap (a combined 25GB!) and crashed while opening the project. I need to get a static library out of it, and then I can manually import the headers, which shouldn't be a problem. What configure/make/cmake command [combinations] would I need to run?

Note: I only need the functions in the Index.h file if it makes any difference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created a series of articles for building clang.

- [llvm / Clang hacking - Part 1](http://aussiebloke.blogspot.com/2012/06/llvm-clang-hacking-part-1.html)
- [llvm / Clang hacking - Part 2](http://aussiebloke.blogspot.com/2012/06/llvm-clang-hacking-part-2.html)
- [llvm / Clang hacking - Part 3](http://aussiebloke.blogspot.com/2012/06/llvm-clang-hacking-part-3.html)

You'll have some additional challenges building for iOS, but this would be a starting point.

Comment: @corristo When compiling with the flags below and in this answer, I get the error `/Users/josh/Documents/xcode/iCode/libclang/build/llvm-build-make/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:36:10: fatal error: 'cmath' file not found` when building LLVM with make. Any suggestions? I'm lost as to why. Some Google-ing says that [it goes away after building a few times](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-March/020366.html), but that didn't work for me.

Comment: looks like DataTypes.h included in non-c++ file so it can't find c++-specific include =\ Strange, does it build ok for OS X?

Comment: @JoshTheGeek Since you accepted this answer, did these instructions help you do successfully compile Clang for armv7?

Comment: I'm trying to do pretty the same, but i'm having strange behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045633/dyld-library-not-loaded-error Were you able to do it finally?

Answer (score 2):

generate simple makefiles instead os Xcode project and then build using make?

Use this one to configure cmake/make build to build for iOS:
[How can I make Cmake use specific compiler and flags when final compilation stage instead of detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476203/how-can-i-make-cmake-use-specific-compiler-and-flags-when-final-compilation-stag)

Comment: But if I just do ./configure && make that would build for OS X, correct?

Comment: hmm yes I missed that, sorry. Then try to use xcodebuild to build xcode project without opening it.

Comment: so, this link isn't sufficient to you?