# "dyld: Library not loaded" error

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, clang

i have successfully compiled static library and added it to the XCode project just like it's written in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/configuration.html):

1. libclang.a file is in project directory (added file copy and group)
2. libclang.a is listed in "Frameworks"
3. i've added '-Objc' linker flag to 'Other linker flags'.
4. libclang.a is listed in "Copy bundle resources"

libclang.a is compiled for ios simulator:

```
MBA-Anton:llvm_34_build_i386 asmirnov$ lipo -info ../llvm_34_ios_i386_installed/lib/libclang.a
input file ../llvm_34_ios_i386_installed/lib/libclang.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: ../llvm_34_ios_i386_installed/lib/libclang.a is architecture: i386
```

I'm able to build the project but i'm getting error while ios simulator starts the app:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libclang.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/asmirnov/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/D87A3FA9-7207-40B4-9EA0-5F06CEF6EF7B/StaticLibraryUsage.app/StaticLibraryUsage
  Reason: image not found
```

I have found similar questions but it seems i did everything what was recommended. Any thoughts?

PS. I have libclang.dylib file but i'm not sure it's really needed since i have added libclang.a file in the project.

PPS. I have compiled armv7 version of libclang.a and created fat library with both i386 and armv7 using `lipo`. After removing i386 version of libclang.a and adding fat version of libclang.a i have [multiple unresolved references for i386 arch build errors.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051087/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-lipo-error)

PPPS. I have resolved "unresolved references" errors by adding all libLLVM*.a files in the project. but now i'm having original "dyld: Library not loaded".

PPPPS: .m compile command-line:

```
CompileC /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Intermediates/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASAppDelegate.o StaticLibraryUsage2/ASAppDelegate.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/iOS_Projects/StaticLibraryUsage2
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DDEBUG=1 -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -iquote /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Intermediates/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/StaticLibraryUsage2-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Intermediates/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/StaticLibraryUsage2-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Intermediates/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/StaticLibraryUsage2-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Intermediates/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/StaticLibraryUsage2-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Intermediates/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Intermediates/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -include /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/StaticLibraryUsage2-Prefix-baynabgphydhcmapwpcclpqhagrv/StaticLibraryUsage2-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Intermediates/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASAppDelegate.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Intermediates/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASAppDelegate.dia -c /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/iOS_Projects/StaticLibraryUsage2/StaticLibraryUsage2/ASAppDelegate.m -o /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Intermediates/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASAppDelegate.o
```

link command-line:

```
Ld /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.app/StaticLibraryUsage2 normal i386
    cd /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/iOS_Projects/StaticLibraryUsage2
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34_ios_fat_installed -L/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/iOS_Projects/StaticLibraryUsage2/StaticLibraryUsage2 -L/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34_ios_i386_installed_2/lib -F/Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Intermediates/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Objects-normal/i386/StaticLibraryUsage2.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lstdc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMSystemZAsmParser -lLLVMAArch64CodeGen -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMMCJIT -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMPowerPCInfo -lLLVMHexagonAsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMPowerPCAsmParser -lclangDriver -lLLVMARMInfo -lLLVMAArch64AsmParser -lLLVMHexagonDesc -lLLVMipa -lclangARCMigrate -lLLVMMipsDesc -lLLVMNVPTXCodeGen -lLLVMBitWriter -lLLVMXCoreDisassembler -lLLVMNVPTXDesc -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMHexagonInfo -lLLVMSystemZAsmPrinter -lLLVMTableGen -lLLVMSystemZCodeGen -lLLVMInstrumentation -lLLVMAArch64Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter -lLLVMCppBackendInfo -lclangBasic -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMDebugInfo -lLLVMAArch64Utils -lLLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter -framework CoreGraphics -lLLVMAsmParser -lLLVMSparcCodeGen -lclangFormat -lLLVMXCoreDesc -lLLVMipo -lLLVMObject -lclang -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMPowerPCDesc -lLLVMXCoreCodeGen -lLLVMVectorize -lclangAST -lclangSema -lclangTooling -lLLVMIRReader -lLLVMMipsCodeGen -lclangRewriteCore -lLLVMXCoreAsmPrinter -lLLVMMSP430Desc -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMR600Info -lLLVMMipsAsmPrinter -lLLVMMipsAsmParser -lLLVMMCDisassembler -lLLVMBitReader -lclangAnalysis -lclangStaticAnalyzerCore -lLLVMMipsDisassembler -lLLVMR600AsmPrinter -lLLVMR600CodeGen -lLLVMAArch64Info -lclangDynamicASTMatchers -lLLVMARMAsmPrinter -lLLVMXCoreInfo -lclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend -lLLVMMipsInfo -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMSparcInfo -lLLVMR600Desc -lLLVMOption -lLLVMAArch64Desc -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMJIT -lclangEdit -lLLVMSystemZDesc -lLLVMARMDesc -lLLVMSparcDesc -lLLVMMC -lLLVMMSP430CodeGen -lLTO -lLLVMHexagonCodeGen -lLLVMMSP430AsmPrinter -framework UIKit -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMMSP430Info -lLLVMARMCodeGen -lLLVMARMAsmParser -lclangCodeGen -lLLVMLinker -lLLVMPowerPCCodeGen -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMSystemZInfo -framework Foundation -lclangASTMatchers -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter -lLLVMARMDisassembler -lLLVMNVPTXInfo -lclangParse -lclangIndex -lclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers -lclangRewriteFrontend -lLLVMInterpreter -lclangLex -lLLVMCppBackendCodeGen -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMCore -lLLVMLTO -lclangFrontend -lclangFrontendTool -lLLVMSupport -lLLVMSystemZDisassembler -lclangSerialization -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Intermediates/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Objects-normal/i386/StaticLibraryUsage2_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.app/StaticLibraryUsage2
```

libclang.a adding to executable command-line:

```
CpResource /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34_ios_i386_installed_2/lib/libclang.a /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PocketIDE-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.app/libclang.a
    cd /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/iOS_Projects/StaticLibraryUsage2
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34_ios_i386_installed_2/lib/libclang.a /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PocketIDE-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.app
```

controller code to test libclang:

```
#import "Index.h"

// ...

// show diagnostics
void showHighlight(CXTranslationUnit TU, const char *src_filename, unsigned filesize)
{
    if (TU)
        NSLog(@"Translation unit valid: %s\n", src_filename);

    CXFile file = clang_getFile(TU, src_filename);

    if (file)
        NSLog(@"file is valid, size = %i\n", filesize);

    unsigned int line, column, offset;

    CXToken *tokens;
    unsigned numTokens;

    // range = all the file
    CXSourceLocation beginning = clang_getLocationForOffset(TU, file, 0);
    CXSourceLocation end = clang_getLocationForOffset(TU, file, filesize);
    CXSourceRange range = clang_getRange(beginning, end);

    clang_tokenize(TU, range, &tokens, &numTokens);

    NSLog(@"%i tokens:\n", numTokens);

    for (int i=0; i<numTokens; i++) {
        CXToken token = tokens[i];

        CXTokenKind kind = clang_getTokenKind(token);
        CXSourceLocation location = clang_getTokenLocation(TU, token);
        clang_getSpellingLocation(location, &file, &line, &column, &offset);
        CXString filename = clang_getFileName(file);
        CXString spelling = clang_getTokenSpelling(TU, token);

        NSLog(@"kind=[%s], [%s %i:%i offset=%i] [%s]\n",
                kinds[kind], clang_getCString(filename), line, column, offset, clang_getCString(spelling));

        clang_disposeString(filename);
        clang_disposeString(spelling);
    }

    clang_disposeTokens(TU, tokens, numTokens);
}

unsigned getfilesize(const char* filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    unsigned sz = ftell(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return sz;
}
- (void)testClang
{
    NSLog(@"started");

    // get file from bundle
    NSString *ns_filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test_hl" ofType:@"cpp"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:ns_filename];
    NSLog(@"file %@ exists: %d", ns_filename, fileExists);

    CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(false, false);

    // command-line tu
    const char *filename = [ns_filename UTF8String];
    const char *argv = { filename };
    int argc = 1;
    CXTranslationUnit commandLineTu = clang_parseTranslationUnit(index, 0, &argv, argc, 0, 0, CXTranslationUnit_None);

    unsigned filesize = getfilesize(filename);
    showHighlight(commandLineTu, filename, filesize);

    clang_disposeTranslationUnit(commandLineTu);
    clang_disposeIndex(index);

    NSLog(@"finished");
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self testClang];
}
```

Comment: I don't understand "libclang.a is listed in *Copy bundle resources*".  Why would it be copied into the resources folder?

Comment: you're right. this is not required, it can be removed from "copy bundle resources" and it does not affect it -i still have this error

Comment: Well it looks like you just need to set-up the run path of the executable to include `@loader_path/../Frameworks` (which is where your `.dylib` files should be copied to in the app bundle).  Look at the linker build settings to set-up the run-path.

Comment: should i add libclang.dylib in "frameworks" and to "copy bundle resources" (even if libclang.a is added)?

Comment: Yes, and the `.a` file should not be needed at all (they contain the same code, one for statically linking and the other for dynamically linking).

Comment: sorry, i can't understand. it's written that ios does not support dynamic linking - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733847/can-you-build-dynamic-libraries-for-ios-and-load-them-at-runtime. I also tried to add libclang.dylib to "frameworks" and "copy bundle resources" and i'm still having this error

Comment: Ah, that's true.  Just dump the `.dylib` and link against the `.a` files.  No copying is then required to the app bundle.

Comment: ok, i've added .dylib in "frameworks" and "copy bundle resource" - still having error. What should i do step-by-step?

Comment: You said yourself that iOS doesn't support dynamic libraries, so you cannot do that.  You'll have to use static libraries throughout.

Comment: ok, so why .dylib is needed by ios simulator and what should i do with .a files in order to make the app working?

Comment: I've no idea why the simulator needs the .dylib file.  You link against the `.a` files during build and they are not required after that.  Often you need to use *Additional Linker Flags* with options like `../path/to/files/libclang.a` in order to link against the `.a` files instead of the `.dylib` files.

Comment: I've pasted link command-line and it has -lclang and -L with .a path so i'm in stuck

Comment: Why are you stuck?  You cannot remove those options?

Comment: -l and -L are options to link against libclang.a and they are added by XCode so i can't understand what you're trying to say to me.

Comment: It's trying to dynamically link against libclang.dylib, you want it to statically link against libclang.a. Check your project settings.

Comment: what should i check exactly? i've describes current settings in the question

Answer (score 4):

What this error is sadly trying to tell you is that lib clang thinks its @rpath is at the root of your app bundle, but it's not.

I figured this out the hard way just the other day.
It's hard.
You have to do some crazy stuff with libclang.a using Build Phase settings.
In your target's Build Phases, you will need to add a few Run Script Phases.

One will be this:

```
echo "warning: OTOOL BEGIN1";
pwd;
otool -L ${SRCROOT}/Clangwrap/ClangAndLLVM/lib/libclang.dylib;
echo "Warning: OTOOL END1";
```

This just does a few things.
First it nicely sandwiches things with a log to see what happened.
The second is it really is just confirming the path to your lib once it's copied. (and yes, you should be copying it into your project to keep things sane.)
otool does this.
SRCROOT is the root of your project, then anything after that is your relative path within you project's folder in Finder to the lib you are going to use.

Again, this just confirms it is where you think it is.

Ok, next step. This is the real doozy.

```
echo "BEGIN install_name_tool";
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/libclang.dylib ${SRCROOT}/Clangwrap/ClangAndLLVM/lib/libclang.dylib;
echo "END install_name_tool";
```

This runs the obscure command line tool install_name_tool and that is used to set the path where the lib thinks it is located within your app's bundle. Without doing this, the lib will think it is in some other path. You will be setting this path to what you intend it to be. In a Mac app, I used the Frameworks folder inside the bundle so I set it as such. The first argument to install_name_tool is the relative path in your app bundle where the lib is going to be. The second argument is where the lib is currently in your project so that install_name_tool can set its executable path. 
This literally modifies a bit of the lib so it is loadable. libs must know their own load path.

Note the first step is only optional for your own sanity.
The second step is required, and both should occur before the Compile Sources Build Phase. 
Click and drag to move them up.

Now the final step. Add a new Copy Files Phase and this will remain last in your build phases.
Set the destination to the same as the first arg of install_name_tool so you know your relative path is set and that's where you're going to put the lib.
I used Frameworks.
Now add the files to this Build Phase, for iPhone, add libclang.a (I don't think you can use libclang.dylib on iOS)

Note, you saw me use libclang.dylib and that's because I did this on a Mac app project. It should be the same process for just about anything.

this is not an easy or discoverable process, I pieced it together from several blogs and docs.

Comment: I think using `@rpath` is much easier than doing all that stuff.  You also don't explain how to set-up the executable in order to find the `.dylib` in `@loader_path/../Frameworks` as setting the `id` of the `.dylib` won't do it.

Comment: @uuchuugaka. Sorry, afaik dynamic linking is not supported in iOS apps. Is this dynamic linking? Will this prevent the app to be distributed via App Store?

Comment: Well it is if you use the dylib but not if you use the .a file his error is the dylib error. He never says he's submitting it to the store. I'm not sure if clang would make it in the store.

Comment: @trojanfoe come again? install_name_tool sets the `@rpath`

Comment: Nothing in your answer sets anything in the executable.  You need to reference the `.dylib` files using `@rpath/name.dylib` and set the *run-path* of the executable when linking it.

Comment: @uuchuugaka i'm not going to use clang to compile, just for highlighting (via C API) so i don't think it will make the app rejected by Apple

Comment: @trojanfoe `install_name_tool -id `sets it. Referencing it is just a matter of setting the paths inBuild Settings and importing or including in your code.

Comment: It's not that easy though is it; for one thing you normally link against a `.dylib` which is outside of the app bundle and after linking you copy any `.dylib` files into your app bundle and during that stage you make your `install_name_tool` changes.  It seems like a bad idea to me to modify those files outside of the app bundle just so the dynamic linker will work correctly.  It's easier to use `@rpath` by a long way.

Comment: But you cannot copy the file until there is a place to copy it to.

Comment: @4ntoine , *very recent* versions of Xcode and the iOS SDK allow dynamic linking. You cannot use those versions (yet) for app store submission, however.

Comment: That's great news. It means a real decision in minimum SDK version

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on how to fix it for dynamic linking but i'm not going to use dynamic linking. I need answers on how to fix it for static linking

Comment: I think static linking would end up being basically the same with a different @rpath, except, you need to then worry about symbols clashing. You can either build the static lib to the destination path, or you can shell script it the same way later.