# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 - Lipo error?

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, static-libraries, lipo

I have compiled libclang.a for i386 and armv7. I'm able to build my ios app with i386 libclang.so but it can't be started because of [".dylib not found" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045633/dyld-library-not-loaded-error). Then i decided to create fat lib using lipo:

`lipo -create ../i386/libclang.a ../armv7/libclang.a -output ../fat/libclang.a`

and added fat library instead of i386.

Now i'm getting multiple build errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "llvm::TimeRecord::getCurrentTime(bool)", referenced from:
      clang::cxindex::Logger::~Logger() in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
  "llvm::raw_ostream::flush_nonempty()", referenced from:
      clang::cxindex::Logger::~Logger() in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
  "llvm::raw_ostream::write(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _clang_createTranslationUnit in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      _clang_parseTranslationUnit in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      _clang_saveTranslationUnit in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      clang::cxindex::Logger::operator<<(CXTranslationUnitImpl*) in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      _clang_getCursorDisplayName in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      _clang_annotateTokens in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      clang::cxindex::Logger::operator<<(clang::FileEntry const*) in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      ...
  "llvm::raw_ostream::write(unsigned char)", referenced from:
      _clang_saveTranslationUnit in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      clang::cxindex::Logger::operator<<(CXTranslationUnitImpl*) in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      _clang_tokenize in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      _clang_annotateTokens in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      clang::cxindex::Logger::~Logger() in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
  "llvm::raw_ostream::operator<<(llvm::format_object_base const&)", referenced from:
      _clang_getCursor in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      clang::cxindex::Logger::operator<<(llvm::format_object_base const&) in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      clang::cxindex::Logger::operator<<(CXSourceRange) in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      clang::cxindex::Logger::operator<<(CXSourceLocation) in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      clang::cxindex::Logger::~Logger() in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
  "llvm::raw_ostream::operator<<(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      clang::cxindex::Logger::~Logger() in libclang.a(CIndex.o)
      _clang_formatDiagnostic in libclang.a(CIndexDiagnostic.o)
  "llvm::MemoryBuffer::getMemBufferCopy(llvm::StringRef, llvm::StringRef)", referenced from:
```

Does it mean lipo has created incorrect fat lib? How can i solve it? I need the app to run on both ios simulator and device.

PS.

```
MBA-Anton:llvm_34_ios_fat_installed asmirnov$ lipo -info ../iOS_Projects/StaticLibraryUsage2/StaticLibraryUsage2/libclang.a
Architectures in the fat file: ../iOS_Projects/StaticLibraryUsage2/StaticLibraryUsage2/libclang.a are: i386 armv7
```

PPS. Xcode build command-line:

```
Ld /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProjectE-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.app/StaticLibraryUsage2 normal i386
    cd /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/iOS_Projects/StaticLibraryUsage2
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProjectE-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34_ios_fat_installed -L/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/iOS_Projects/StaticLibraryUsage2/StaticLibraryUsage2 -L/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34_ios_i386_installed/lib -F/Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProjectE-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProjectE-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Intermediates/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Objects-normal/i386/StaticLibraryUsage2.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework CoreGraphics -lclang -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProjectE-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Intermediates/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.build/Objects-normal/i386/StaticLibraryUsage2_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProjectE-axtxqjlvmrcxqsfnvgobybceosvb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/StaticLibraryUsage2.app/StaticLibraryUsage2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add all libLLVM*.a files in the project and the project was compiled successfully. But i have runtime error now:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libclang.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/asmirnov/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/99583E4A-2848-4D44-A3DC-88218D911B46/StaticLibraryUsage2.app/StaticLibraryUsage2
  Reason: image not found
```

I'm not sure if it's related problem or i've solved that problem and now having another problem.