# "Do Not Embed", "Embed & Sign", "Embed Without Signing". What are they?. What they do?

Tags: ios, frameworks, static-libraries, xcode11, dynamic-library

We have 3 new options in "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" section of Xcode11 Beta for adding libraries.

**Xcode Libraries section screenshot**

[image]

Can anyone explain what they do?

Comment: I guess "embed" means "copy into app bundle".  I also guess the "sign" bit really means "re-sign" using your credentials.

Answer (score 73):

*As already stated by @przemyslaw-jablonski, this is similar to what was in Xcode 10, but in only one screen (which I personally like!).*

---

### Embedding

*Do not embed static frameworks and libraries (linking happens at build time), only shared ones (dynamic linking happens at run time, so they need to be in your bundle).*

`file frameworkToLink.framework/frameworkToLink` will return:

- `current ar archive`: static library, select `Do not embed`
- `Mach-O dynamically linked`: shared library, select `Embed`

---

### Signing (only if shared/embedded)

*Not required if it already has a proper signature (adhoc doesn't count).*

`codesign -dv frameworkToLink.framework` will return:

- `code object is not signed at all` or `adhoc`: select `Embed and sign`
- anything else: already properly signed, select `Embed Without Signing`

Comment: If result of `file` is `Mach-O universal binary`, what should be the right choice?

Comment: As to `codesign`, I found that if the framework is signed with a `adhoc` signature, it'll still be necessary to sign it, or else the app can't be launched.

Comment: @Mint: universal binary means it has different architectures underneath. The architectures underneath should tell you if they are archives or dynamic libraries

Comment: Does this also apply to standard frameworks such as the **AdSupport.framework** or should they be set to "Do not Embed" as they are already present on the device?

Comment: Good question. That framework isn't static? I believe you should not embed it if you know it will be available on the target system, even if it's shared. The best way to know is to test without embedding it, and it will complain at runtime if it can't load that library. Please let us know so we can edit the answer accordingly!

Answer (score 15):

Basically in Xcode 10 in project settings (upon clicking on .xcodeproj file, with the blue icon) you had two framework-oriented sections visible - Embedded Binaries and Linked Frameworks and Libraries. Now they are merged into one.

`Do Not Embed` option is basically Linking given .framework into project.

`Embed & Sign` and `Embed Without Signing` is old Embedding option.

I am not entirely sure what is the functional difference between the last two, apart from the fact that framework will or will not be signed during assembly. If you want to know the difference between Linking and Embedding then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33210611/6942800) you can find SO answer on this.

Pics:

[image: Xcode 10]

[image: Xcode 11]

Comment: Earlier under "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" the options were "Required" and "Optional" Is "Required" same as "Do not Embed" ?

Comment: @RBz no, `optional` status for supporting earlier versions as weak dependencies. Check the manual: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html

Answer (score 14):

**Xcode v11. Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content plus Frameworks and Libraries with Embed vs Do Not Embed**

[image]

History

```
Embedded Binaries, Linked Frameworks and Libraries -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content
```

[[Xcode pre-v11. Embedded Binaries, Linked Frameworks and Libraries]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216858/4770877) existed till to Xcode v11 section in `General` tab

It is a part of `Dependency` management [<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215808/4770877)

Xcode v11 has:

- App target - `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`
- Framework or App extension target - `Frameworks and Libraries`

### Embedding

**Embed**

It adds a copy of the framework into your final bundle. After that `Dynamic linker :dyld` at **load or run time** tries to find the **embedded framework** using `@rpath`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216681/4770877) If it is not found the error will occur [<sup>[dyld: Library not loaded]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216681/4770877)

`Embed` is a mirror of `Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks`. Here you can setup bundle's folder and `Subpath`.

**Do Not Embed**

`Static Linker` at compile time tries to copy code from a static library into the executable object file using `Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths`

`Do Not Embed` is a mirror of `Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries`. `Sign` is a mirror of `Code Sign On Copy`

If you do not add a `static framework` to this section you will get a compile error[<sup>[No such module]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216742/4770877)

Result:

- static library
- static framework - Do Not Embed
- dynamic framework - Embed

[image]
[image]

*Please note that `Embedding` has bigger priority than `Mach-O Type`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61035316/4770877)

- Application's `Frameworks, Libraries...` is `Embed` and Framework's `Mach-O` is `Static Library` - result dynamic framework.
- Application's `Frameworks, Libraries...` is `Do Not Embed` and Framework's `Mach-O` is `Dynamic Library` and - result error `dyld: Library not loaded`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216681/4770877)

```
App's Embed (Dynamic) -> Framework's Mach-O Static - Dynamic
App's Do Not Embed(Static) -> Framework's Mach-O Dynamic - error
```

[[Static vs Dynamic linker]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57741985/4770877)
[[When use Link and Embed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57500670/4770877)
[[Vocabulary]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877)

Answer (score 14):

The complete story holyswift

[image]

for more [details](https://holyswift.app/frameworks-embed-or-not-embed-thats-the-question)