# What is Do Not Embed, Embed & Sign, Embed without Signing meaning in Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, embed

In Framework, Library and Embedded Content has three kind of embed:
- Do Not Embed
- Embed & Sign
- Embed without Signing

I don't know what are the differences between these 3 kinds. Can you explain the meaning of three kinds. Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57687170/do-not-embed-embed-sign-embed-without-signing-what-are-they-what-th

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Do Not Embed", "Embed & Sign", "Embed Without Signing". What are they?. What they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57687170/do-not-embed-embed-sign-embed-without-signing-what-are-they-what-th)