# How to use system supplied and/or external library in swift program in Xcode 12.5?

Tags: c, swift, xcode

I'm trying to use some version of libpcre in a swift program for macOS, through **Xcode 12.5**. I can't seem to get the system to find the libraries I have tried.

Search on this topic on the web is maddening, because nothing really seems to be complete. I'd like to ask for 2 pathways:

**Library which comes with Xcode/macOS**

If I look at my target info panel in the project editor, I can add **Frameworks and Libraries**. I would like to add libpcre.

I hit the "+", scroll down and select `libpcre.tbd`. It dutifully adds an entry.

How do I now use this in a swift file, and see the various functions from the pcre library?

**Library installed from Homebrew**

Say I have decided that pcre version 1 isn't enough, and I need to add libpcre2. I use "brew install pcre2", which installs the files in /usr/local/Cellar/pcre2/10.36/ .

How do I now show Xcode how to find these libraries, and use them in my swift file?

**The Test**

In both cases, my basic test is that I ought to be able to type

```
let recode = pcre<ESC>
```

and have Xcode show me the various symbols from the included library.

Comment: I suppose you need to create a bridging header file for it so that you can import the file to the project.

Comment: I suspect the system included file isn't a supported thing, and just an random inclusion from PHP.

I've also learned that to include the pcre2.h library (in the bridging header), you first must define PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH to 8, 16, or 32.

I'd still love a canonical explanation of how to use a system library, and a homebrew library.

Comment: Do you know the exact header file name you are trying to import to the project with libpcre.tbd?

Comment: No. In fact, I'm not sure there is one. It's not clear to me that Xcode tries to do the right thing here. It seems like I can pick that library, and it'll try to include it, but it's not clear at all that it'll make it actually available to the developer.

This is why I'm hoping for an explanation from someone who knows the insides of Xcode really well.

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63269154   http://rustyrazorblade.com/post/2008/external-libraries-in-xcode/    https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/263171977ebcd47f4aaca1202cff5a96c5158a64/Documentation/Usage.md#import-system-libraries

Comment: or have a look how they did it: https://github.com/DimaRU/Shout.git