# Code Signature Version is not Supported - Error

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I tried to run my app on my old iPhone 8+, and I am getting the error that the code version isn't supported. I went into my Targers and into Build Settings, and under *Other Code Signed Flags*, I put `--generate-entitlement-der` in the Debug and Release SDKs.

Then a popup comes that I cannot install my app on the phone, and this dialog appears;

```
Unable to install "Polygon"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-07-09 01:43:20 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
The code signature version is no longer supported.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008029)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011e009614         
DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011e042dd8 __90-    
[DTDKMobileDeviceToken 
installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 160
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101b0dbd0 
DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 76
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011e042b30 - 
[DTDKMobileDeviceToken 
installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1336
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011c4b9590 __118- 
[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) 
processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.301 + 
2916
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101c34f50 
__DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101c36068 
__DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 364
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001b27ae5f0 
_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001b27b01b4 
_dispatch_client_callout + 20
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001b27b78a8 
_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001b27b8404 _dispatch_lane_invoke 
+ 392
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001b27c2c98 
_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b2970360 _pthread_wqthread + 
288
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b296f080 start_wqthread + 8
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone10,5";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.5 (19F77)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 9167;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402620375";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.6.1";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.5";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.5";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.4 (Build 21F79)
Xcode 13.4.1 (20504) (Build 13F100)
Timestamp: 2022-07-08T21:43:20-04:00
```

Comment: Are you using any third party libraries? I had this issue with some Ad libraries that aren’t shipped as .xcframework’s

Comment: I am using firebase, but it was working fine before I implemented Sign In with Apple.  Was there a problem there, cuz when I moved the code to a different app, using Firebase authentication, it worked.

Comment: How have you added the Firebase SDK? Manually or SPM/CocoaPods?

Comment: I did it through swift package manager.

Comment: It must be a different issue to what I had then. I had to set frameworks to “Do not embed”, but I don’t think SPM’s are embedded anyway.

Comment: How do you set the frameworks to Do Not Embed? it might solve my problem

Comment: In the framework section https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57687170/do-not-embed-embed-sign-embed-without-signing-what-are-they-what-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to make sure to click `do not embed` on the frameworks tab. This allowed it to work properly. Check the settings in Xcode, as mine were set default to `Embed`