# How do I embed a third-party xcframework in my Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I'm trying to embed the following third party framework in my Xcode project: https://dicomhero.com/downloads/ but Xcode complains that `Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code`. I've tried one of several things including:

- `codesign -d -v dicomhero6.xcframework`
- Creating a dummy Swift Package with the framework: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-binary-frameworks-as-swift-packages

But none of them seem to have worked, and Xcode crashes at start time and suggest moving the framework to the Trash. Is this an issue I can fix on my end, or would I have to contact the developer? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the framework only provide a dynamic library?  If it provides a static library, you could add that as a dependency instead.

Comment: Not sure, but [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57687170/do-not-embed-embed-sign-embed-without-signing-what-are-they-what-th) might have some useful info.

Comment: @ChipJarred none of the suggestions really helped but thank you for trying!

Answer (score 2):

I tried to download the framework using the link you provided, and then embed it into an empty project. Xcode showed the alert about using code from untrusted source.

[image: Untrusted Developer Alert]

When you download a file from internet it receives "quarantine" attributes:

```
$ xattr xcframework.zip 
com.apple.macl
com.apple.quarantine
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms
com.apple.lastuseddate#PS
```

`com.apple.macl` and `com.apple.quarantine` are the most interesting here.

Not sure what exactly `macl` means, but I assume it to be some kind of Access Control Layer. The presence of this attribute makes the OS to show this "untrusted developer" alert.

These attributes could be removed with `xattr -d`. `com.apple.quarantine` attr gets removed just fine, however `com.apple.macl` reappears after deleting it.

When you unzip a zip archive by just double clicking on it, Finder re-applies these `com.apple.quarantine` and `com.apple.macl` attributes to the unarchived file or directory. But if you decompress the archive with `unzip`, `com.apple.macl` will not be applied to the decompressed data.

You could download the archive and then do:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ unzip xcframework.zip
$ sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine dicomhero6.xcframework
```

Then drag and drop `.xcframework` to your Xcode project.

Alternatively you get rid of the "developer cannot be verified" error by just opening the Security and Privacy pane in the System Preferences and "Allow Anyway".

[image: Security and Privacy pane]

Comment: I get a 'fopen(/Users/cyril/Downloads/dicomhero6.xcframework/Info.plist, rb): Permission denied (13)' error after dragging to Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Since the 6.0.0.0 release the XCFramework is distributed as a DMG archive.
After unpacking the archive, run

```
xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine dicomhero6.xcframework
```